# Include an integer into a string

Tags: java, string, integer, converters

I would like to ask something simple . I have created a class which will have a name.
I want to create several of these classes , but the number of them is not exactly known. Every class has a unique name

What I want  :

We have for example 3 classes, then their names should be:

Class #1

Class #2

Class #3.

I am thinking something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numberofclasses ; i++ )
{
    C[i] = new Class("Class # **(i+1)** " );  (where i+1 , is the number of class)   
}
```

P.S. : any suggestions for better title are accepted

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you want to dynamicaly load class ?

Comment: [Are you looking for a way to load a class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4865153/335858) Use `"Class # "+(i+1)` for the class name.

Comment: Doo you really want to create new `Class`es that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my preferred way.  I don't like the `+` because it can also be used for mathematical operations.

```
// Call String.format with three integer codes.
String result = String.format("One: %1$d Two: %2$d Three: %3$d",10, 20, 30);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your question as you actually have several compiled classes with predictable names.

You'll have to use reflection of some sort to load and create instances of the classes.

For example:

```
Class.forName("ClassName").newInstance();
```

This assumes your class has a constructor without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions , the answers that worked for me was :

adding +(my int) after strings

```
System.out.println("Class #"+(i+1))
```

(fast solution )

and 
@Moua Li's answer:

```
String result = String.format("One: %1$d Two: %2$d Three: %3$d",10, 20, 30);
System.out.println(result);
```